# Help in understanding Bochner's theorem and Pontryagin duality theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, definition

I am trying to understand Bochner's theorem through wikipedia link

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem

This refers to dual spaces of locally compact abelian group and leads to Pontryagin duality theorem. Is there a relation between this two theorems. I cannot understand much from the wikipedia links on this theorems, specially the connection if exists. Any comments would be welcome.